# Unable to Refresh Token using Spring ClientCredentialsResourceDetails

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth

I am using ClientCredentialsResourceDetails to setup my OAuth2RestTemplate object.

My OAuth2 enabled api is sending me back refresh_token in the response, which can be used to refresh access tokens.

However, Spring does not implement token refresh for ClientCredentialsResourceDetails object as it can be seen [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/token/grant/client/ClientCredentialsAccessTokenProvider.java#L32)

Is there a way to get token refresh working or am I doing anything incorrect ?

FYI, this is my piece of spring code for oauth beans

```
@Bean
@Primary
public OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails oAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails() {
    final ClientCredentialsResourceDetails resourceDetails = new ClientCredentialsResourceDetails();
    resourceDetails.setClientId(clientKey);
    resourceDetails.setClientSecret(clientSecret);

    final URI accessTokenUri = UriComponentsBuilder.newInstance()
            .host(host)
            .path(tokenUrlPath)
            .scheme(scheme)
            .build()
            .toUri();

    resourceDetails.setAccessTokenUri(accessTokenUri.toString());
    resourceDetails.setClientAuthenticationScheme(AuthenticationScheme.header);

    return resourceDetails;
}

@Bean
public OAuth2RestTemplate oAuth2RestTemplate(
        OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails oAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails
) {
    final OAuth2RestTemplate oAuth2RestTemplate = new OAuth2RestTemplate(oAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails);
    oAuth2RestTemplate.setRequestFactory(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory());
    return oAuth2RestTemplate;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because "[4.4.3. Access Token Response](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.4.3)" in [RFC 6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749) (The OAuth 2.0 Authorization Framework) says as follows:

> If the access token request is valid and authorized, the authorization server issues an access token as described in Section 5.1.  **A refresh token SHOULD NOT be included.**  If the request failed client authentication or is invalid, the authorization server returns an error response as described in Section 5.2.

In short, **[Client Credentials Flow](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.4) should not issue a refresh token**. Spring complies with the requirement.

Comment: Is there a way we can have one api call another api with automatic refresh token in spring boot?